# Find all tags in given namespace

Tags: java, jsoup, xml-namespaces

How can I find all tags in a given namespace?

Sample XML extract:

```
<myNamespace:tag1>
    <myNamespace:tag2>test</myNamespace:tag2>
    <span>test2</span>
</myNamespace:tag1>
```

I want to get a list with tags that are in `myNamespace`:

- `myNamespace:tag1`
- `myNamespace:tag2`

I tried `myDocument.select("myNamespace|")` but unfortunately it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

This is a modified answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764992/parse-xml-nodes-having-text-with-any-namespace-using-jsoup) link, I edited it for your situation:

```
// Elements of any tag, but with 'types' are stored here
Elements namespaces = new Elements();

// Select all elements
for( Element element : doc.select("*") )
{
    // Split the tag by ':'
    final String s[] = element.tagName().split(":");

    /*
     * If there's a namespace (otherwise s.length == 1) use the 2nd
     * part and check if the element namespace is "myNamespace"
     */
    if( s.length > 1 && s[0].equals("myNamespace") == true )   
    {
        // Add this element to the found elements list
        namespaces.add(element);
    }
}
```

Comment: doc would be your xml content