# Jsoup match any element with a namespace

Tags: java, css, xml, scala, jsoup

I would like to return all element with a particular namespace for example `<server:cpu> <server:memory>` using Jsoup css selector.

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse("<server:cpu> <server:memory>");
Elements el = doc.select("sever|*");
```

<strike>But that return a `Could not parse query` exception</strike>

This documentation https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html says you can use :

> *|E   elements of type E in any namespace ns

but I want to do the opposite: get element in namespace ns of any type. Is this possible?

EDIT: 
I am not getting the exception anymore, however I am getting an empty Elements object after executing `doc.select("sever|*");`

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem. Also right under quoted line we can see `ns|E elements of type E in the namespace ns` which suggest `sever|*` should work. BTW `Jsoup.parse("file.xhtml");` doesn't try to find and parse `file.xhtml` file, but will treat `"file.xhtml"` as raw data which needs to be parsed.

Comment: Maybe you are using older version of Jsoup. It seems to be working on `1.10.1` and `1.10.2`.

Comment: @Pshemo "Jsoup.parse("file.xhtml");" was just an example. I will fix it to address your consern. However saying, `suggest server|* should work` doesn't confirm anything. I have already tried that and it doesn't work.

Comment: @Pshemo I am using version 1.10.2

Comment: Depending on your real use case possible solution could be crating your own iterator which will traverse over all nodes and check if name of tag starts with `server:`. If yes then add such element/node to list holding such elements. Here is one example http://stackoverflow.com/a/23766900.

Comment: I will give it a try. It sucks Jsoup doesn't support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote something in Scala to accomplish namespace matching with wildcard (*) i.e ("namespace|*") since it is not supported in JSoup version 1.10.2

```
def getElementsByNamespace(element: org.jsoup.nodes.Element, namespace: String): org.jsoup.select.Elements = {
    import collection.JavaConverters._
    val elements = element.select("*").asScala.filter(_.tagName().startsWith(s"$namespace:"))
    new Elements(elements.asJava)
  }
```

For java version please refer the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/23766900 suggested by @Pshemo

Thanks to @NaderHadjiGhanbari for help me understand and convert from Java collection to Scala collection