# Scala doesn't cast Element inside loop to yield value

Tags: java, scala, jsoup

I am fairly new to scala. I have this method to filter all Elements -from Jsoup library- that start with a given namespace.

```
def getElementsByNamespace(element: org.jsoup.nodes.Element, namespace: String) : org.jsoup.select.Elements = {
    val elements = 
      for {
        el <- element.select("*")
        if el.tagName().startWith(namespace+":")
      } yield el
    elements
  }
```

In this example `<root><server:cpu></server:cpu><server:ram></server:ram><a></a></root>` the method will get all elements that start with `server`

The problem is that scala is casting `el <- element.select("*")` as `Any` and not as `Element` which is the type returned by the method select (It actually returns an Elements object or an ArrayList)

For that reason, when I call `if el.tagName().startWith(namespace+":")` tagName() is not found and therefore the code doesn't compile.

I have tried filter, withFilter, etc but still not working.

Why is this happening? How can I make this code better?

Comment: This does not answer the problem of why you cannot use `Elements` in a for comprehension, but why don't you use the `select(namespace|*)` syntax to get the same result?

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Not true. As per Jsoup version 1.10.2 , that functionality is not supported. You can certainly do `select('*|element')` but not the other way around. I have tested it many times and it returns an empty Elements object

Comment: This thread -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23764992/parse-xml-nodes-having-text-with-any-namespace-using-jsoup/23766900#23766900 states the above mentioned functionality is not supported by JSoup even though it's part of the CSS specification

Comment: That's weird, I saw this in Jsoup documentation: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: The linked documentation doesn't talk about using the wildcard * to match all element in a particular namespace.

Comment: You're right about that, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short Answer (tl;dr)

The problem is you need to convert between Scala and Java collections:

```
def getElementsByNamespace(element: org.jsoup.nodes.Element, namespace: String): org.jsoup.select.Elements = {
    import collection.JavaConverters._
    val elements = for {
      el <- element.select("*").asScala
      if el.tagName().startsWith(s"$namespace:")
    } yield el
    new Elements(elements.asJava)
  }
```

### Explanation

In order to iterate over a collection in Scala you can use `flatMap`, `map`, or for comprehensions. There is no other way (like the `for` and `foreach` loops in Java).

But the thing is Java collections are not directly supported because they would need a `flatMap` method defined on them. `flatMap` is the essence of iteration (the other two methods are also defined based on `flatMap`).

That's why you need to convert the the variable of `Elements` type to a Scala collection (import `JavaConverters._` and call `asScala` method on Java collections).

At the end, you need to construct a new `Elements` but constructors of that class, understandably, just accept Java collections, so you need to convert the result of your for comprehension, which is a Scala collection, to a Java collection.

Comment: Unless the code is just for learning purposes, use the `select(namespace|*)` method mentioned by @Cyrille in comments, it's a selector which gives you exactly what you want: all elements of a given namespace.

Comment: As per  Jsoup version 1.10.2 , that functionality is not supported. You can certainly do `select('*|element')` but not the other way around. I have tested it many times and it returns an empty Elements object

Answer (score 1):

I think that you may want to add import `scala.collenction.JavaConversions._`
Thing is `Elements` class, the one returned by `select` method does not support for comprehensions - as it is extension of `ArrayList` and hence does not have `map`, `flatMap` and `filter` methods - unless you do implicit conversion to one of scala collections.